# Looking for a way to automatically signin to a windows based login using ip address in web browser

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, server, ip

I have setup a server at `192.168.18.40`. Server works fine. I am using windows profile. So every time I use this IP address, it asks for sign in which I must enter into a popup window.

[image: Sign in Screen]

There is no security concern. I don't want this window to popup. I want my `html` page to somehow automatically enter username and password and sign in (I guess using `javascript` or something). I have searched everywhere for the answer but could not find one. Username and Password is the same as one of the windows local profiles.

Comment: If this is your server, why does it require authentication in the first place? Can't you switch that off?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen I wish I could do that. I am experimenting with power bi report server. I made a virtual server, only hosting reports which don't require any security. But report server does not allow antonymous access. Don't want to get into certificates and other fancy security setups for a server having no sensitive information (the entire thing is a virtual machine).

Comment: You said that several people should access the report server. Shall they each use their own user and password? Or is there a "technical user" which they all share?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen I used a guest account which users shared. Its a virtual machine specifically made for sharing purpose. No sensitive data to worry about. For now I am using a hyperlink containing user id and password (http://user:pass@url). But I am looking for a similar alternate as they are going to disallow this in future.

Comment: Does the "Custom" authentication type described here in the [Power BI Report Server documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/security/authentication-with-the-report-server?view=sql-server-ver16#authentication-types) help?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for "Chrome browser extension to Automatically login to Basic Authentication"

You may use the one linked below or search for it yourself

MultiPass for HTTP basic authentication
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/multipass-for-http-basic/enhldmjbphoeibbpdhmjkchohnidgnah

Comment: This worked perfectly, but for me only. The ip address is embedded in an html file which I want to share with people and I want similar thing to do using code in that html file. So that it sign itself in automatically just like this extension.

Comment: Wait, this is basic auth? Then URL can contain them, lemme find docs

Comment: @ShahidLatif see https://serverfault.com/questions/371907/can-you-pass-user-pass-for-http-basic-authentication-in-url-parameters

Comment: yes, we can use url. they have already blocked url with username and password in most of the browsers including chrome. and we cannot use it in iframes. http://user:pass@url works fine for now using javascript. Looking for a better alternate. way around CORs is also a pain.